# How to mock a coldbox.system.web.context.RequestContext and initialize it?

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, coldbox

I have inherited some code at my work. A previous person wrote some ColdFusion code that looks like this:

```
public struct function GetData(Event,RC,PRC){};
```

I am trying to write a unit-test for this function but I don't know how to mock this "Event".
This is my code:

```
mockEvent=createMock(className='coldbox.system.web.context.RequestContext');
```

ColdBox is throwing an exception that I must initialize `mockEvent` when I run that code. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer your question but perhaps looking over the documentation will help - [Creating a Mock Object](https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/content/mockbox/creating_a_mock_object.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a test, which extends the `Coldbox.system.testing.BaseTestCase`, you can easily mock the Coldbox RequestContext object.

You need to set the following variable in your tests : `this.loadColdbox=true` and then, after you call the `super.beforeAll()` method from within your test, each time you call `setup()`, the context is rebuilt.

After that, the RequestContext is available with the method `getRequestContext()`. Here's an example of mocking the request `getHTTPMethod()` function (I typically use this method to mock API methods which are configured to respond to different HTTP verbs):

```
function newEventArgs( method = "GET" ) {
        //rebuild the context
        setup();
        //mock the context
        var event = getRequestContext();
        prepareMock( event ).$( "getHTTPMethod", arguments.method );
        var rc = event.getCollection();
        var prc = event.getCollection( private=true );
        prc.response = getWirebox().getInstance( "APIResponse" );

        return {
            "event":event,
            "rc":rc,
            "prc":prc
        };
}
```

Then you might test a create method like so:

```
it( "Tests Widgets.create", function(){

        var testWidget = {
            "name"  : "Test Widget"
        };

        var eventArgs = newEventArgs( "POST" );

        structAppend( eventArgs.rc, testWidget, true );

        var event = execute( 
            route="/api/v1/widgets"
            eventArgs=eventArgs
        );

        expect( event.getPrivateValue( "response" ).getStatusCode() ).toBe( 201, "Event response did not return the proper status code." );

});
```